# ionic 2 white screen on android 4.2.2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I try to run an ionic 2 sample app on my android device, but the only thing I see, is a white screen. To start the app, I use the command

```
ionic run android
```

When I start in Chrome, everything works fine. I also tried to find the error over

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

but, I can't found any devices, other ionic 1 apps works well.

Any solutions?

### Update

I use this sample app: https://github.com/ccoenraets/ionic2-realty-rest
But i have the same result with the starter app over the ionic cli. Now I also add crosswalk: `ionic browser add crosswalk`, but no luck.

Comment: where you are trying to run the app on emulator or device?

Comment: ... sample app on my android device....

Comment: you should add crosswalk like this `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and answering here because I resolved it.
After much hassle I tried to use an older ionic 2 version with

```
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
```

A new project then build and run succesfully on 4.2.2 device.
It just seems that the 2.1.0-beta.1 was/is buggy.

There was absolutely no difference with or without cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview. (And I was seriously fed up with always reading that tip ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by installing crosswalk plugin via CLI

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

After adding this plugin the app showed up on my device with Android version 4.2.2.

Still doesn't work. Try adding these to config.xml:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="17+"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="~1.6.1"/>
```

And consider resetting ionic state using the command below on CLI

```
ionic state reset
```

Comment: This has some pretty big [drawbacks](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview). Any chance you could explain exactly what this does? I'm struggling to understand the readme.

Comment: Crosswalk can be used on older android versions in case you are facing issues in getting the app working. Basically its a different webUI by crosswalk with makes  rendering possible on older devices too. You are right, the drawbacks are hefty.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer, working with ionic 3.x too :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be you are running into this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/898

In short, 4.2.2 is supported but crosswalk is recommended. Also update to the latest beta if you are running on an older one.

Comment: sorry to hear that. Just to make sure, how did you add crosswalk? you should do it like this: ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview